# a⊙b=0 if and only if a=0 ∨ b=0.

Tags: number-theory, proof-writing, modular-arithmetic

[image]

I don't see how this holds, or maybe I'm understanding modular arithmetic incorrectly. If $n = 12$ then $a ⊙ b = 0$ can be satisfied by $a = 3$ and $b = 4$ no?

I see how this holds when I write the proof for it.

If $(a * b)$ mod $n = 0$, $a * b = n$.

We can rewrite $a ⊙ b = 0$ as:
$ab + kn  = 0$, now as $ab + ab(k) = 0$.

Factoring out an $ab$ we get $ab( 1 + k) = 0$.

Since $k$ is $a \geq 0$, $a*b = 0$, meaning $a ∨ b = 0$.

But I still don't see how this makes sense!

Comment: Does ⊙ mean multiplication modulo $n$?  The implication holds for prime $n$

Comment: $a*b\equiv0\pmod n$ means $a*b=\color{red}kn$ for some $k$, not necessarily $a*b=n$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This hold for prime numbers. Because if $a \times b$ is the choosen prime n, then $a$ or $b$ is $n$ and the other is 1

Comment: If n is prime, and a = n and b = 1, then how does the statement hold? a is not 0 nor is b. Sorry, I'm having a lot of difficulty understanding this  :(

Comment: in $\mathbb{Z}_n$ if $a=k n, k \in \mathbb{Z}$ then we can say that $a=0$

Comment: $n$ is $0$ in $\mathbb Z_n$

Comment: @DaniJo If you are having difficulties understanding what is going on here, you might want to check what I wrote here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3200827/how-to-remember-n-modulo-m-operations-better/3200853#3200853 maybe it helps.